# Div doesn't have the right height

Tags: html, css

My div is not the right height (see picture below), it was supposed to be higher but it stops in the middle of the div (the section with the different icons is in the same div). I don't know why so can you please help me?

[image]

And here is my html:

```
    <div class="features">
    <div class="row">
        <hgroup>
            <h2>Features</h2>
            <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</h3>
        </hgroup>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <i class="ion-social-wordpress"></i>
                <h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc consequat enim et nisi volutpat vulputate. Aliquam dictum libero id viverra volutpat. Nullam justo nisl, suscipit id neque facilisis, scelerisque placerat erat.</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <i class="ion-iphone"></i>
                <h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc consequat enim et nisi volutpat vulputate. Aliquam dictum libero id viverra volutpat. Nullam justo nisl, suscipit id neque facilisis, scelerisque placerat erat.</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <i class="ion-person"></i>
                <h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc consequat enim et nisi volutpat vulputate. Aliquam dictum libero id viverra volutpat. Nullam justo nisl, suscipit id neque facilisis, scelerisque placerat erat.</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <i class="ion-cash"></i>
                <h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc consequat enim et nisi volutpat vulputate. Aliquam dictum libero id viverra volutpat. Nullam justo nisl, suscipit id neque facilisis, scelerisque placerat erat.</p>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my css (it is in scss):

```
    $basecolor: #5aadf0;
$hover: #3b9eed;
$time: 0.3s;
/* ------------------------------------------- */
/* Basic setup  */
/* ------------------------------------------- */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #555;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; 
}

/* ------------------------------------------- */
/* Reusable */
/* ------------------------------------------- */

.row {
    width: 1140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

    /* ------------------------------------------- */
    /* Headers */
    /* ------------------------------------------- */
    h2 {
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 200%;
        word-spacing: 8px;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
    }

    h2:after {
        display: block;
        height: 2px;
        background-color: $basecolor;
        content: " ";
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 15px;
    }

    h3 {
        font-size: 110%;
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        padding: 25px 0;
    }

    h4 {
        font-size: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        padding: 10px 0;
    }

    h4:after {
        display: block;
        height: 2px;
        background-color: $basecolor;
        content: " ";
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 8px;
    }

    /* ------------------------------------------- */
    /* Text */
    /* ------------------------------------------- */
    .info-text {
        font-size: 100%;
    }

    /* ------------------------------------------- */
    /* Buttons */
    /* ------------------------------------------- */

    .btn {
        padding: 10px 15px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        border-radius: 300px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .full-btn:link,
    .full-btn:visited {
        border: 1px solid $basecolor;
        color: white;
        background-color: $basecolor;
        transition: background-color $time, border-color $time;
    }

    .full-btn:hover,
    .full-btn:active {
        background-color: $hover;
        border-color: $hover;
    }

    .ghost-btn:link,
    .ghost-btn:visited {
        border: 1px solid $basecolor;
        color: $basecolor;
        transition: border-color $time, color $time, border-color $time;
    }

    .ghost-btn:hover,
    .ghost-btn:active {
        border-color: $hover;
        color: $hover;
        background-color: $hover;
        color: #fff;
    }

/* ------------------------------------------- */
/* Header */
/* ------------------------------------------- */
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(../img/hero.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;

    .hero-text-box {
        position: absolute;
        width: 1140px;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

        .hero-btn {
            width: 100%;
            margin-top: 30px;

            .full-btn {
                margin-right: 10px;
            }
        }

        h1 {
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 280%;
            font-weight: 300;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            word-spacing: 4px;
            letter-spacing: 1px;
        }
    }
}

/* ------------------------------------------- */
/* Navigation bar */
/* ------------------------------------------- */
nav {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 100%;

    .logo {
            height: 100px;
            width: auto;
            float: left;
            margin: 20px 0;
    }

    .main-nav {
        float: right;
        list-style: none;
        margin-top: 55px;

        li {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-left: 40px;

            a:link, a:visited {
                color: #fff;
                text-decoration: none;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                font-size: 100%;
                border: 2px solid transparent;
                transition: border-bottom $time; 
                padding: 8px;
            }

            a:hover, a:active {
                border-bottom: 2px solid $basecolor;
                border-radius: 3px;
            }
        }   
    }
}

/* ------------------------------------------- */
/* Info Section */
/* ------------------------------------------- */
.info {
    padding: 50px 0;
    width: 100%;

    hgroup {
        h2:after {
            width: 35%;
        }
    }
}

/* ------------------------------------------- */
/* Features section */
/* ------------------------------------------- */
.features {
    padding: 50px 0;
    width: 100%;

    hgroup {
        h2:after {
            width: 25%;
        }
    }

    ul {
        width: 100%;

        li {
            display: inline-block;
            float: left;
            width: 25%;
            padding: 20px;

            i {
                font-size: 400%;
                text-align: center;
                color: $basecolor;
                display: inline-block;
                width: 100%;
            }

            h4:after {
                width: 100%;
            }

            p {
                font-size: 100%;
            }
        }
    }
}

/* ------------------------------------------- */
/* About section */
/* ------------------------------------------- */
.about {
    padding: 50px 0;
    width: 100%;

    hgroup {
        h2:after {
            width: 20%;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I would like the div to wrap around all the elements in the div, including unordered list which it doesn't do now.

Comment: Please explain correctly how you want the div to be shown and what should be in it and what should not.

Comment: Try clearing your floats, could be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're floating your `<li>` elements inside the `.features` div, but you're not clearing the floats.

```
ul:after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

[Here is a Codepen demonstrating your issue.](http://codepen.io/taniarascia/pen/rxNavZ)

[Here is a Codepen demonstrating the solution.](http://codepen.io/taniarascia/pen/adbzKX)

Comment: You're welcome! Please consider choosing this as the accepted answer if you were satisfied so that other users know the issue has been resolved.